# Expresión regular para limpiar etiquetas HTML en Python

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un crawler que extrae contenido de un blog, lo ejecuto y guardo en un CVS para luego trabajarlo, el problema es que quiero limpiar un poco el HTML que me devuelve del contenido.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Articulo(Item):
    titulo = Field()
    contenido = Field()
    url = Field()

class UdekaCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bomberoninja'
    custom_settings = {
         'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0',
         'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 10
    }
 download_delay = 1
 allowed_domains = ['bombero.ninja']
 start_urls = ['https://bombero.ninja/articulos/']
 rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=r'/articulo/',
            deny=('.*category.*'
                  '.*author.*',
                  '.*page.*',
                  '.*tag.*'
                  ),
        ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'
    ),
  )

    def limpiarTexto(self, texto):
         nuevoTexto = texto.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').strip()
    return nuevoTexto


def parse_items(self, response):
    item = ItemLoader(Articulo(), response)
    item.add_xpath('titulo', '//h1/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiarTexto))
    item.add_xpath('contenido', '//div[@class="elementor-element elementor-element-560a34ac elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-post-content"]', MapCompose(self.limpiarTexto))

    url = response.url
    item.add_value('url', url)

    yield item.load_item()
```

Tengo esta parte en el cñodigo anterior que limpia el texto de espacios en blanco:

```
def limpiarTexto(self, texto):
             nuevoTexto = texto.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').strip()
        return nuevoTexto
```

Lo que me gustaría poder eliminar todas las etiquetas `<div>`, `<image>`, `<figure>` etc

Comment: Esta pregunta me está recordando a la famosa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: es un wordpress, podes pedir un feed sin tanto div, onda  https://bombero.ninja/articulos/feed/

Comment: Parece ser que scrapy mismo tiene su método para eliminar tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando y buscando y probando y probando encontré la forma de hacerlo, el siguiente código limpia la etiquetas (en este caso div, figure, img) y deja el texto que haya enmedio:

```
def limpiarTexto(self, texto):
        nuevoTexto = re.sub('(<(div*\w+)\s[^>][^>]*>|<div*\w+>|<\/div*\w+>|<(figure*\w+)\s[^>][^>]*>|<figure*\w+>|<\/figure*\w+>|<(img*\w+)\s[^>][^>]*>|<img*\w+>|<\/img*\w+>)', '', texto)
        return nuevoTexto
```

Answer (score 0):

El módulo **re** sirve para escribir expresiones regulares

```
import re

def limpiarTexto(self, texto):
    nuevoTexto = re.sub('(\n|\r|\s)', ' ', texto)
    nuevoTexto = re.sub('(<div>|<image>|<figure>)', '', nuevoTexto)
    return nuevoTexto
```

En esta página puedes practicar las expresiones regulares para reemplazarlas en python: https://regex101.com/

Dentro de la búsqueda de la expresión regular, podrías buscarlos textualmente o generalizando para eliminar todo lo que esté entre **<>**

```
nuevoTexto = re.sub('(<div>|<image>|<figure>)', '', nuevoTexto) # Textual
nuevoTexto = re.sub('((<\/\w+>|<\w+>))', '', nuevoTexto) # General
```

Comment: probé lo que me pasaste pero me las etiquetas que tiene alguna clase me las mantiene ¿como puedo hacer para que las elimine también?